# Spring 3 and a custom object wrapper for FreeMarker

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

How do you configure Spring 3 to use a custom object wrapper to use with FreeMarker?

I've created a custom object wrapper for FreeMarker but I'm not sure how you configure Spring 3 to use the wrapper. The following has no effect:

    `<bean id="freemarkerConfig"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
        <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/classes/templates/"/>
        <property name="freemarkerSettings">
            <props>
                <prop key="object_wrapper">my.custom.ObjectWrapper</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>`

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: you have to create another bean which will instanstiate ObjectWrapper then reference that bean(Object Wrapper), ex: `<property name="freemarkerSettings" ref="objectWrapper">` where objectWrapper is bean id

Answer (score 0):

`FreemarkerView` auto-detects the `FreeMarkerConfigurer` bean in the context, and gets the config from that. Obviously, you have to be using `FreemarkerView` correctly in order for this to work, but you haven't told us anything about how you're using freemarker.